# Section heading recognition

Tags: python-sphinx

I am running Sphinx 1.8.2 under Eclipse Photon in Windows 10 using Python3.7.2. I am having problems getting Sphinx to accept my section heading structure.Consider the following textual source:

```
***********************
Development Environment
***********************

Computer Support
================

The following tools are used to support the computer environment.

 Assessment and Deployment
 -------------------------

 This is a collection of tools supplied by Microsoft which support unattended installation of Windows.

 SIM
 ^^^

 Used to create an unattended.xml file that supplies the answers to questions posed during Windows during install.

 HP Support Assistant
 --------------------

 Personal
 ========

 LibreOffice
 -----------

 Adobe Creative Cloud - Photography Plan
 ---------------------------------------


Development Support
===================

Java
-----

Eclipse
-------

Pydev
^^^^^

Regex
"""""

Requests
""""""""

Sphinx
""""""

Sphinx ReadThe Docs Theme
"""""""""""""""""""""""""

Liclipse Text Editor
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Notepad++
```

---

This generates the following errors:

```
Running Sphinx v1.8.2
loading pickled environment... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 1 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [] 0 added, 1 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] DevEnvironment                                       

D:\Shared\WiseOldbird\Projects\Platform IndependentApplicationController\docs\source\DevEnvironment.rst:11: WARNING: Unexpected section title.

Assessment and Deployment
-------------------------
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... D:\Shared\WiseOldbird\Projects\Platform IndependentApplicationController\docs\source\DevEnvironment.rst:16: WARNING: Unexpected section title.

SIM
^^^
D:\Shared\WiseOldbird\Projects\Platform IndependentApplicationController\docs\source\DevEnvironment.rst:21: WARNING: Unexpected section title.

HP Support Assistant
--------------------
D:\Shared\WiseOldbird\Projects\Platform IndependentApplicationController\docs\source\DevEnvironment.rst:24: WARNING: Unexpected section title.

Personal
========
D:\Shared\WiseOldbird\Projects\Platform IndependentApplicationController\docs\source\DevEnvironment.rst:27: WARNING: Unexpected section title.

LibreOffice
-----------
D:\Shared\WiseOldbird\Projects\Platform IndependentApplicationController\docs\source\DevEnvironment.rst:30: WARNING: Unexpected section title.

Adobe Creative Cloud - Photography Plan
---------------------------------------
done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [ 50%] DevEnvironment                                        
writing output... [100%] index                                                 

generating indices... genindex
writing additional pages... search
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en) ... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 6 warnings.

The HTML pages are in build.
```

and it renders as HTML in Google Chrome as follows

What do I need to do to get Sphinx to accept my heading structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't indent the lines.  This should work.

```
***********************
Development Environment
***********************

Computer Support
================

The following tools are used to support the computer environment.

Assessment and Deployment
-------------------------

This is a collection of tools supplied by Microsoft which support unattended installation of Windows.

SIM
^^^

Used to create an unattended.xml file that supplies the answers to questions posed during Windows during install.

HP Support Assistant
--------------------

Personal
========

LibreOffice
-----------

Adobe Creative Cloud - Photography Plan
---------------------------------------


Development Support
===================

Java
-----

Eclipse
-------

Pydev
^^^^^

Regex
"""""

Requests
""""""""

Sphinx
""""""

Sphinx ReadThe Docs Theme
"""""""""""""""""""""""""

Liclipse Text Editor
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Notepad++
```

Comment: I can't see where I am indenting

Comment: In the question, the "Assessment and Deployment" heading and the five headings after that are indented by one column.

Comment: @Jonathan the 6 warnings explicitly state which lines are indented, e.g. `D:\Shared\WiseOldbird\Projects\Platform IndependentApplicationController\docs\source\DevEnvironment.rst:11: WARNING: Unexpected section title.` It's always a good idea to pay attention to the feedback Sphinx provides, even if it is not clear what the exact problem may be. "Unexpected section title" does not say "Unexpected indent", but at least the line number should direct you to the location of the problem.

Comment: The problem was that I could not recognize the lines were indented by one space.